# Google not showing promt to select google account

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0, google-apps, google-workspace

We have web application with keycloak as identity broker, google SAML app as IDP for google managed workspace for domain say mycompany.com. Integration works fine for except a case described below.

If user is logged in with only one non SAML app google account, google returns

> 403 Error: app_not_configured_for_user.

i.e. If I am logged as with my personal gmail acccount & not with mycompany.com account

[image]

I have inspected SAML AuthnRequest payload SAML tracer which has `ForceAuthn="true"` but still it does not show up account chooser page.

I went through couple of stackoverflow threads. Few provided solution about using account chooser url and redirecting it to auth page `https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser?continue={theredirectURL}`.

Looking at community to help suggesting clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

This error pretty much depends on which account is the primary one in the Google account chooser as it always takes that to complete the sign in process automatically.

There is no official way or setting from Google to do this, however the mosto commonly used workaround is to add the following URL to the `Start URL` section of the SAML app settings for it to force the authentication whenever you click on it.

> [https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=[REPLACE]s&spid=[REPLACE]&forceauthn=false](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=%5BREPLACE%5Ds&spid=%5BREPLACE%5D&forceauthn=false)

There are 2 parameters that you need to replace in that URL and you need to get them from the Google apps menu next to your profile picture, then hover over the SAML app that you want to change and right click on it, then copy the link address and that will show the `idpid` and `spid` values.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ffernando-lara
I have setup the Start URL as you mentioned & REPLACED correct idpid & spid values. But still I face the same issue. 
Want to confirm following,
1. letter "s" after idpid=[REPLACE] i.e. idpid=[REPLACE]s is incorrect & should be idpid=[REPLACE]
2. Editing app & adding Start URL will apply change immediately

Thanks & looking for further help

Comment: You are totally right, the start URL should look something like this `https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C08z9y2zx&spid=676216516034&forceauthn=false`

Comment: These changes can also have propagation time depending on how many OUs you will be updating. For my testing I changed it for a single OU that has a single user so it was updated immediately.

Comment: I have testes Saml app with configuration that you mentioned also waited for propagation. I still get the same error.
Could you please help me resolving this issue ?

Comment: From the link I provided did you replace the `idpid` and the `spid` parameters with your own info?

Comment: Yes I replaced correct values for idpid & spid

Comment: There have been many conversations about this particular issue on stackoverflow since 2017 and many developers talked about the workaround which didn't work and the dev community still ask if they have found a solution on those threads

Can Google tech team look into it & acknowledge if it's a bug. A fix or proper solution is going to help the community a lot. There isn't much on the SAML Service Provider side to control the account selection part. 

I tried the same scenario with Google OAuth 2 and it works fine. I can conclude that Google SAML App  has this issue.